# Splitting a number of rows in two different database tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

with this code I am able to put content into my database (more specific http://puu.sh/4vO16.png)
Now what I want is that the code puts the first half (in this case two rows) in a table called A and the second half in a table called B.

Is this possible? If so, would you help me? thanks!

```
// Enter New Data To Table
$uitvoer = getTable($url);
foreach ($uitvoer as $row) {
   $query = array();
   $insert = "";
   $insert_values = "";

   foreach ($row as $col) {
       $query[] = strip_tags($col);
   }

   $insert_values = implode("','", $query) ;
   $insert = "'".$insert_values."'";

   $sql="INSERT INTO " . $tableName . " (id, naam, punten, NUMwedstrijden, NUMgewonnen, NUMverloren, GEWsets, VERLsets, forfait) VALUES ($insert)";

   mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}
```

Comment: You need to create a primary key for your table.

Comment: you could just change $tableName in the loop after a few iterations.
where do you define this variable?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Why? Can't see what that has to do with this.

Comment: @Cylindric It would have prevented this from happening in the first place.

Comment: use transactions for insert more than one table in same action..

Answer (score 0):

I hope this fits your needs;

```
$uitvoer = getTable($url);
$counter = 0; 

foreach ($uitvoer as $row) {

   $tableName = "talbeA";
   if ((count($uitvoer) / 2) <= $counter) $tableName = "tableB";
   //the magic happens on the line above

   $query = array();
   $insert = "";
   $insert_values = "";

   foreach ($row as $col) {

       $query[] = strip_tags($col);

   }

   $insert_values = implode("','", $query) ;
   $insert = "'".$insert_values."'";

   $sql="INSERT INTO " . $tableName . " (id, naam, punten, NUMwedstrijden, NUMgewonnen, NUMverloren, GEWsets, VERLsets, forfait) VALUES ($insert)";

   mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   $counter++;

}
```

this is very weird question I think, If I get it right and you just want to divide inserts in **half** (as you mention in your question) this is it.